# What is the block time of Hyperledger Sawtooth PoET?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

As the title says, does it have a fixed block time or is it just defined by the random waiting period of the nodes?
Is there an estimation how long this could be by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks do not have a fixed size nor is there a fixed time to generate a block.  Also, Sawtooth supports multiple consensus algorithms.  For PoET, each node generates a random wait time and the first node with an expired timer wins. For PoET, the following settings are relevant:

- `sawtooth.poet.initial_wait_time`
  For C Test: initial time to wait in seconds before proposing a block (e.g., 25; default 3000)
- `sawtooth.poet.target_wait_time`
  Target time to wait in seconds before proposing a block (e.g., 5; default 20)

Comment: So this means target wait time will be something like an average which the random waiting time generator will consider?